# How to get all users whose subscriptions will expired today using Laravel Cashier

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am working on a application developed on Laravel/Vue having subscription payments on stripe, Currently I require users from stripe/Database whose subscriptions will expires today so that i set their status as expired in database, how can i get those users from Databases using Laravel/Cashier?

Answer (score 1):

Cashier can't really do everything for everyone. There are two ways to go around this:

1. Use fixed subscription renewal dates (recommended) that way everyone expires at the same time. Calculating will be a matter of checking no of days till the fixed day in month.
2. Create a field in your subscription model like `subscription_expires_at` same way you have `trial_ends_at`. [Define a webhook controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#defining-webhook-event-handlers) to set/update the expiry once a subscription has been created/updated. This way you can query the model normally with `where('subscrition_expires_at', '>', now())`. The specific events you want to hook are `customer.subscription.created` and `customer.subscription.updated`